# JETT loop 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for each row

Tags: jett

I use `<jt:forEach>` Tag to loop but I want add a column to return row number such as:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Example 
1  fldTest1   fldTest2
2  fldTest1   fldTest2
3  fldTest1   fldTest2
4  fldTest1   fldTest2
....

Row number starts from `1` and `count++`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the JETT documentation for the `jt:forEach` tag (http://jett.sourceforge.net/tags/forEach.html):

*Attribute **indexVar**: This specifies an integer "counter" variable name to be exposed in the beans map. This variable starts at index zero.*

Since you want to start at 1, just add one to the value.

For example:

| Index | Employee Name |

| `<jt:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee" indexVar="employeeIndex">` ${employeeIndex + 1} | ${employee.name} `</jt:forEach>`|